# select certain days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to build a select tag with only specific days for example Mon ... Fri, how can I generate that in rails 2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe use something like [calendar date select](http://code.google.com/p/calendardateselect/). You can then indicate that certain dates can be disabled as indicated [here](http://code.google.com/p/calendardateselect/wiki/HowToDisableDates). Would look something like:

```
<%= calendar_date_select_tag "week_day", "", 
              :valid_date_check => "date.getDay() != 0 && date.getDay() != 6 " %>
```

Answer (score 5):

I can't quite believe this is really what you want but

```
options_for_select(["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"])
```

does what you've asked ;)

Comment: With an extra " after "Tue 8)